# Implementing Graph as a map of maps

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, hashmap

I am implementing the graph data structure in Java as a Map of maps.

The Graph object is a map of data(key) and all vertices(value)

```
public class GraphAdjMap<T> implements IGraph<T> {

private Map<T, Vertex<T>> vertices = new HashMap<T, Vertex<T>>();
```

Each vertex is a map of edges where key is the destination vertex and value is the edge object:

```
class Vertex<T> {

private T data;
private Map<T, Edge<T>> edges = new HashMap<T, Edge<T>>();
```

Edge is a simple value object:

```
public class Edge<T> {  
    private T destination;
    private int weight;
```

With this structure its easy and fast for me to answer a lot of queries like:
Are 2 edges connected?
What are all the edges of a vertex?
Is this vertex connected to the other vertex?
How many edges does a vertex have?
etc...

Is this a good implementation or am I missing something?

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: I think, edges shouldn't be `HashMap`, but some kind of unmodifiable map.

Comment: This and similar implementations are common. Usually with mappings from Vertices to the Set of Edges. Depending on whether the graph is *directed* or *undirected*, this may be separated into "incoming edges" and "outgoing edges". Many queries can there be done in O(k) time, where "k" is the maximum vertex degree. (The important thing usually is that the time does not depend on the *total* number of vertices). In the end, it depends on which operations your *algorithms* will need, but your current choice is reasonable - and in doubt, you have an interface, and can change the implementation

Comment: @ChrisOdney, because you mustn't change this value after initializing the vertex.

Comment: BTW: My other comment referred to the **conceptual** choice of implementing the **structure** like this, and not to the actual implementation. It could simply be a `Map<V, Set<E>>`, for example

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg How can that be when you have to keep adding new edges or removing existing edges.

Comment: @Marco13 Got it. I too had a Set initially but changed it to a Map as it speeds up a few queries.

Comment: If you can post more complete code, this kind of question _may_ get better answers at Code Review.  If you want to ask here, try asking a more specific question about graph data structures.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom There is nothing much else in the code that is more important. Mostly just getters and setters.